# How to resolve 'module 'metpy' has no attribute 'calc'' error when using MetPy in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, github, metpy

I have got this error with metpy:

```
AttributeError: module 'metpy' has no attribute 'calc'
```

The code is as follows;

```py
import metpy as mp
import numpy as np
from metpy.units import units

df = pd.read_csv('wind.csv', header = 0)
u = (df['u10'].to_numpy()) *units("m/s")
v = (df['v10'].to_numpy()) *units("m/s")
df['speed'] = mp.calc.wind_speed(u, v)
```

Versions: **numpy 1.23.5** **metpy 1.5.0**

Any idea how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the full python traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep imports as quick as possible and streamlined, `import metpy` does not import the subpackages, it essentially only sets up xarray intergrations. If you want to use `metpy.calc`, you need to do `import metpy.calc`:

```py
    import metpy.calc as mpcalc
    from metpy.units import units
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv('wind.csv', header = 0)
    u = (df['u10'].to_numpy()) * units("m/s")
    v = (df['v10'].to_numpy()) * units("m/s")
    speed = mpcalc.wind_speed(u, v)
```